# R loop for NA replacement with mode of row

Tags: r, for-loop, replace, null, mode

```
head(df)
    Name    Score1    Score2    Score3    Score4    Score5
1   John     2           2        NA        3         NA
2   Sam      1           NA        3        1          1
```

I am trying to write a loop to go through each row and replace the NA for each user with the mode of their scores; So for example, the NA's for John would be replaced with a '2', and for Sam, a '1';

I currently have this for the mode calculation, but can't figure out how to replace the NA's in the same loop with that row's mode.

```
Mode <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  if(na.rm){
    x = x[!is.na(x)]
  }

  ux <- unique(x)
  return(ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))])
 }



df$Row_Mode <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(df){
  df[row,]$Row_Mode <- as.numeric(Mode(df[row,2:6]))
}
```

In this loop, how can I simultaneously replace the NA's with the mode for that user?

Comment: `apply(df, 1, function(x) is.na(x) <- Mode(x)` should work. I'll test.

Comment: @plafort: You'd want `apply(df, 1, function(x){x[is.na(x)] <- Mode(x); x})` rather than just `is.na(x) <- Mode(x)`.

Comment: I think you all meant `t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <- Mode(x) ; x}))`, otherwse it won't work. While `Mode` is per `Mode <- function(x, na.rm = TRUE) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than looping, you can simply `apply` the function over the rows of the data frame, then transpose the result. Note that the `Name` column must be omitted, as David Arenburg pointed out.

As Frank mentioned in a comment, you can directly replace the rows other than the `Name` column using `df[, -1]`.

```
df[, -1] <- t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x){x[is.na(x)] <- Mode(x); x}))
df
#   Name Score1 Score2 Score3 Score4 Score5
# 1 John      2      2      2      3      2
# 2  Sam      1      1      3      1      1
```

This assumes that `Mode` is defined as in your question.

Comment: this works great. however, the 'Mode' function needs to be the same as defined in the post which accounts for not including NA values in the mode calculation. great job Alex A.